# Rewrite URL Prefix Using Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, url-rewriting

I am retrieving some data from an external API using javascript, I'm then displaying this data on a HTML page.

Within this returned data is a URL, it's in the following format;

```
var url = https://img.evbuc.com/moreStuff
```

I need to rewrite this URL so that it's prefixed with `www`, like this;

```
var url = https://www.img.evbuc.com/moreStuff
```

I want to achieve this using either javascript or jquery.

How can I achieve this? An explanation of the correct code would be great too.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need regex for this you can simply use [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) api

```js
let url = "https://img.evbuc.com/moreStuff"

let parsed = new URL(url)

parsed.host = parsed.host.startsWith('www.') ? parsed.host : "www."+ parsed.host

console.log(parsed)
```

Comment: True. But no [IE support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=url) (if that matters)

Comment: @Codekie we do have polyfills for that [URL polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-polyfill)

Comment: If you want to use polyfills that is.

Comment: If I worried about IE support, all I'd do is worry about IE support.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to search and replace.

Following example also works with:

- `http://img.evbuc.com/moreStuff`
- `//img.evbuc.com/moreStuff`
- `https://img.evbuc.com/moreStuff//someMoreStuff`

```js
function prependUrl(url) {
  return url.replace(/^([^\/]*)(\/\/)(.*)/, '$1//www.$3');
}

const urls = [
    'https://img.evbuc.com/moreStuff',
    'http://img.evbuc.com/moreStuff',
    '//img.evbuc.com/moreStuff',
    'https://img.evbuc.com/moreStuff//someMoreStuff'
];

urls.forEach((url) => console.log(`${ url } -> ${ prependUrl(url) }`));
```

- The regular expression contains 3 capturing groups:

  1. Select everything up to the first `/` (excluding)
  2. Select the `//` (for protocol root)
  3. Select the rest
- The replacement value takes everything up to the first `/` (which may be an empty string as well)
- Replace the `//` with `//www.`
- Append the rest

Answer (score 1):

If you want something that will work with any protocol, try this regex:

```
var url = "https://img.evbuc.com/moreStuff"
var new_url = url.replace(/^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\.\+\-]*):\/\//, "$1://www.")
console.log('new URL: ', new_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple string operations:

```js
var url = 'https://img.evbuc.com/moreStuff'
var newUrl = url.split('//')[0] + '//www.' + url.split('//')[1]
console.log(newUrl)
```

and yet another way to do this is like this:

```js
var url = 'https://img.evbuc.com/moreStuff'
var newUrl = url.replace('https://', 'https://www.')
console.log(newUrl)
```